# How can i switch Radio Button color on ant design - react?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, design-patterns, antd

I am using a library called Ant Design that uses a color theme throughout the interface but the radio button component does not have the property to change it easily, my goal is to switch the color of the radio button when pressing the trash button.

from this ->
[trash button not selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDCp9.png)
to this
[trash button selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1ZkE.png)

the method I use here is to change the component's css with !important as follows:

```
.ant-radio-button-checked,
.ant-radio-button-inner,
.ant-radio-button-inner,
.ant-radio-button-wrapper-checked,
.ant-radio-button-input:focus,
.ant-radio-button-inner {
  border-color: #ff4d4f !important;
  color: #ff4d4f !important;
}

.ant-radio:hover,
.ant-radio-button-wrapper:hover {
  color: #ff4d4f;
}
```

but I can't go back this action

my react component is as follows:

```
import { React, useState } from 'react';
import { Radio, Button } from 'antd';
import ShopSketch from './ShopSketch';


const Example = () => {
  const [selectedShop, setSelectedShop] = useState(false);
  const [deleteShop, setDeleteShop] = useState(false);
  const [shopNames, setShopNames] = useState(['shop1', 'shop2', 'shop3']);

  return (
    <div>
      <Button danger onClick={() => setDeleteShop(!deleteShop)}>
        <ion-icon
          style={{ color: 'red', fontSize: '18px' }}
          name={deleteShop ? 'close-outline' : 'trash-outline'}
        ></ion-icon>
      </Button>
      <Radio.Group
        className="shops"
        onChange={(e) => {
          const selected = e.target.value;
          setSelectedShop(selected);
        }}
      >
        {shopNames.map((name, index) => (
          <ShopSketch name={name} key={index} deleteShop={deleteShop} />
        ))}
      </Radio.Group>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Example;
```

and the shopSketch Component is:

```
import { Radio } from 'antd';
import { React } from 'react';
const ShopSketch = ({ name, deleteShop }) => {
  return (
    <Radio.Button
      value={name}
      style={{ height: '200px', borderWidth: '2.5px' }}
    >
      <p>{name}</p>
      <ion-icon name="wallet-outline" size="big"></ion-icon>
    </Radio.Button>
  );
};

export default ShopSketch;
```

I tried to change the style directly in the radio button but it affects all the elements, conditionally import the css but I can't revert the action
I ran out of ideas, I know I'm a bit new but I would really appreciate if you could give me any kind of help
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why change the color of the radiobutton if you can change the color of the icon? could you provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?

Comment: Thanks Andrey for your recommendation, I have already made the minimum reproducible code and in time I was able to find a kind of small solution. I could not only change the color of the icon because I wanted to change the color of the border of the button so that the action of deleting a business is more noticeable (it is an important action) and by default the radioButton of ant design has a hover color that also I wanted to change

Answer (score 0):

finally, I was able to come up with a small solution

On example add SelectedShop as argument:

```
<ShopSketch
  name={name}
  key={index}
  deleteShop={deleteShop}
  selectedShop={selectedShop}
/>
```

On ShopSketch add selectedShop and the style to radio.button:

```
const ShopSketch = ({ name, selectedShop, deleteShop }) =>

<Radio.Button
      value={name}
      className={`shop ${deleteShop ? 'shop-delete' : ''}`}
      style={
        selectedShop === name && deleteShop
          ? {
              border: '2.5px solid #ff4d4f',
              color: '#ff4d4f',
            }
          : { borderWidth: '2.5px' }
      }
    >
```

On css:

```
.shop-delete:hover {
  color: #ff4d4f;
}
```